# React state overwrites the current reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, reducers

I have a component called `Restaurante` where I'm trying to call the action `FETCH_ALL` from my restaurante reducer. I'm consuming that information successfully from MongoDB.

To get that information I'm using the useEffect hook where I call the action `getRestaurantes()`

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getRestaurantes());
}, [ currentId, dispatch ]);
```

I have another component called `RestauranteData` which is a table that displays all the information obtained using `dispatch` and the `useSelector` hook

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const restaurantes = useSelector((state) => state.restaurantes);
```

As you can see the information is displaying successfully in the table:

[image: restaurants table]

I need to call another action to get the information from another collection called `consecutitvos`. This collection has information that would allow me to create a custom id when the user creates a new restaurant. To get that information I have an action called `getConsecutivos`.

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getConsecutivos());
    });

const selectedConsecutivo = useSelector((state) => !currentConsecutivo ? state.consecutivos.find((c) => c.type === "Restaurants") : null);
```

The issue that I'm having is that when I call that action the state overwrites and sometimes the table displayed the `consecutitvos` information instead of the restaurants' information. If I reload the page the information displayed in the table changes.

This is the complete code I have in my `Restaurante` component

```
const Restaurante = () => {

    const [currentId, setCurrenteId] = useState(null);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [inputSearchTerm, setinputSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const [selectedTypeSearch, setSelectedTypeSearch] = useState('');
    const [inputSearchTermError, setinputSearchTermError] = useState('');
    const [currentConsecutivo, setCurrentConsecutivo] = useState(null);

    const reload=()=>{window.location.reload()};
   
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getConsecutivos());
    });

   const selectedConsecutivo = useSelector((state) => !currentConsecutivo ? state.consecutivos.find((c) => c.tipo === "Restaurantes") : null);
   console.table(selectedConsecutivo);

    

    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getRestaurantes());
    }, [ currentId, dispatch ]);
```

RestauranteData complete code (Rendering the table)

```
const RestauranteData = ({ setShow, currentId,  setCurrenteId, inputSearchTerm, selectedTypeSearch}) => {

    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const restaurantes = useSelector((state) => state.restaurantes);

    console.log(restaurantes);

    return(
    
        <Table className="text-center" striped>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Dirección</th>
                    <th>Cantidad de Clientes</th>
                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="text-white">
                {restaurantes.filter( restaurante => {

                    if(!inputSearchTerm){
                        return restaurante;

                    }else if( selectedTypeSearch === "codigo"){

                        if(restaurante.codigo.toLowerCase().includes(inputSearchTerm.toLowerCase())){

                            console.table(restaurante);
                            return restaurante;
                        }
                    }else if( selectedTypeSearch === "nombre"){

                        console.log(restaurante.descripcion);

                        if(restaurante.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(inputSearchTerm.toLowerCase())){
                            return restaurante;
                        }
                    }
                }).map( restaurante => {
        
                    return(
                        <tr key={restaurante._id}>
                            <td key={restaurante.codigo}>{restaurante.codigo}</td>
                            <td key={restaurante.nombre}>{restaurante.nombre}</td>
                            <td key={restaurante.direccion}>{restaurante.direccion}</td>
                            <td key="2">2</td>
                            <td key={restaurante.telefono}>{restaurante.telefono}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Button variant="outline-light" className="btn-action" onClick={() => {setCurrenteId(restaurante._id); setShow(true)}} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPen}></FontAwesomeIcon></Button>
                                <Button variant="outline-light" className="btn-action" onClick={() => dispatch(deleteRestaurante(restaurante._id))}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}></FontAwesomeIcon></Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
        
    );
}

export default RestauranteData;
```

restaurantes.js reducer code

```
const reducer = (restaurantes = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DELETE':
            return restaurantes.filter((restaurante) => restaurante._id !== action.payload); //keep all the restaurantes but the action.payload
        case 'UPDATE':
            return restaurantes.map((restaurante) => restaurante._id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : restaurante);
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return [...restaurantes, action.payload];
    
        default:
            return restaurantes;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

consecutivos.js reducers code

```
const reducer = (consecutivos = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DELETE':
            return consecutivos.filter((consecutivo) => consecutivo._id !== action.payload); //keep all the consecutivos but the action.payload
        case 'UPDATE':
            return consecutivos.map((consecutivo) => consecutivo._id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : consecutivo);
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return [...consecutivos, action.payload];
    
        default:
            return consecutivos;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

index.js combined reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import consecutivos from './consecutivos';
import restaurantes from './restaurantes';


export default combineReducers({ consecutivos, restaurantes });
```

index.js of the application

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; //Keep track of the Store
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';

import App from './App';

const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: State is overwritten...? Please include in your question the relevant reducer code that is handling these dispatched actions and updating state. It may help to also include a more comprehensive component code example rendering the table.

Comment: if u add a default state in your reducer function, check your switch function whether the default state exists or not

Comment: the action type name is same in both reducer functions I think that was the problem

Comment: seems restaurantes and consecutivos use same type,  use 'CREATE@RESTAURANTE', 'CREATE@CONSECURTIVO' instead of use CREATE in both create

Comment: Baskaran has it. You are using the same action types in two different reducers, this is triggering the payload processing in the "other" reducer when you don't want it to.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for suggesting adding the reducers code! You knew the issue could be there!

Comment: @BaskaranAjiharan thank you for the response, indeed that was the issue

Comment: @欧阳斌 thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer function, u will use different action type names instead of using the same names &  change action type names in your action methods also

```
const reducer = (restaurantes = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DELETE_RESTAURANT':
            return restaurantes.filter((restaurante) => restaurante._id !== action.payload); //keep all the restaurantes but the action.payload
        case 'UPDATE_RESTAURANT':
            return restaurantes.map((restaurante) => restaurante._id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : restaurante);
        case 'FETCH_ALL_RESTAURANT':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE_RESTAURANT':
            return [...restaurantes, action.payload];
    
        default:
            return restaurantes;
    }
}

export default reducer; 



const reducer = (consecutivos = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DELETE_CONSECUTIVOS':
            return consecutivos.filter((consecutivo) => consecutivo._id !== action.payload); //keep all the consecutivos but the action.payload
        case 'UPDATE_CONSECUTIVOS':
            return consecutivos.map((consecutivo) => consecutivo._id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : consecutivo);
        case 'FETCH_ALL_CONSECUTIVOS':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE_CONSECUTIVOS':
            return [...consecutivos, action.payload];
    
        default:
            return consecutivos;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: I did the changes as you suggested and now it's up and running! Thanks for the help and for taking the time to answer my question!